# Fetching data from related tables

Tags: python, django

I have 3 tables: `Continent`, `Country` and `Story`.

`Country` has `ForeignKey(Continent)` and `Story` has `ManyToManyField(Country, blank=True)` field.

What I need is to get a list of countries which at least have one story belonging to it, and I need these countries grouped by continents.

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do it is:

```
countries = {}

country_list = Country.objects.all()

for c in country_list:
    # check the stories that has the country
    stories = Story.objects.filter(country_set__name__exact=c.name)

    # only if the country have stories
    if stories.count() > 0:
        ## check for initialize list
        if not countries.has_key(c.continent.name):
            countries[c.continent.name] = []

        ## finally we add the country
        countries[c.continent.name].append(c)
```

That will do the work.

Bye

Comment: Thanks that worked but it creates too much queries (271 queries)!